# How can I get the domain name for a user logged into a Mac via Active Directory

Tags: cocoa, macos, active-directory

In my Cocoa app how can I get the current user's domain when they're logged in via Active Directory?

I need to determine two things:

1. If the current user is logged on to an Active Directory domain (only need to handle Active Directory).
2. If 1, the domain of the user.

I've found references to [Directory Services](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Networking/Reference/Open%5FDirectory%5FRef/Reference/reference.html) and the [Open Directory Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/Open%5FDirectory/Introduction/Introduction.html) but the latter is 10.6 only (I must support 10.5+) and I could not find any examples for the former that gave me an idea of what I needed to do.

Answer (score 4):

dsconfigad -show

It will tell whether you are bound to a directory and details about that directory if bound.  Then you will know how to script dscl.

Comment: Thanks. That's a great start, it definitely gets me the name of the domain the computer is bound to. If you use sudo you do not need to specify local credentials (important for using dsadminad programatically). Now is there a way to tell whether the currently logged in user is a domain user or a local account? Poking around so far I haven't been able to figure out a way. If there's a way to do that I will happily accept your answer.

Comment: After poking around more, this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139499/find-active-directory-users-home-folder-from-login-hook-script-in-os-x led me to try fingering the different users, and it appears on my test machine at least that AD users do not have a `Name` (they have a `Login`, but no full name). I'd like a more robust mechanism but if further testing and research shows this to be a fairly reliable method it may suffice.

Comment: I discovered at least one case where a user logged in via Active Directory had a full user name, so that will not work. Still looking.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnston Did you ever find the solution?  I'm trying to figure out the same exact thing.  I have code for parsing the output of dsconfigad -show... but that includes the Active Directory Domain even when run as a user that is not connected to a domain.

Comment: @blak3r No, I did not. Other things came up that were higher priority and so far it hasn't been important enough to go back to. If you find an answer though please share it! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use same idea as here:

[Mac OSX: Determing whether user account is an Active Directory user vs. local user using objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904749/mac-osx-determing-whether-user-account-is-an-active-directory-user-vs-local-us/15284509#15284509)

you just need to look for Network or Authentication node (it's kODNodeTypeAuthentication type) and query it for kODAttributeTypeRecordName with query value set to current user name. Then look at search result, you'll find many interesting things there :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, but note that I assume that you refer to the user that is running the current application, if you are running as root, it won't work.
In case you run it as root, simply change the *NSUserName()* in the query to the desired user you wish to query.

```
std::string getDomainForCurrentUser()
{
    ODSession *session = [ODSession defaultSession];
    ODNode *node = [ODNode nodeWithSession:session type:kODNodeTypeAuthentication error:NULL];
    ODQuery *query = [ODQuery queryWithNode:node forRecordTypes:kODRecordTypeUsers attribute:kODAttributeTypeRecordName matchType:kODMatchEqualTo queryValues:NSUserName() returnAttributes:kODAttributeTypeStandardOnly maximumResults:0 error:NULL];
    NSArray *records = [query resultsAllowingPartial:NO error:NULL];

    for (ODRecord *record in records)
    {
        NSArray *recordLines = [record valuesForAttribute:kODAttributeTypePrimaryNTDomain error:nil];

        if (recordLines)
        {
            NSString *domain = [recordLines firstObject];
            std::string([domain UTF8String]);

        }
    }

    return "";
}
```