# Mac OSX: Determing whether user account is an Active Directory user vs. local user using objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, active-directory

Using `dsconfigad -show` it's possible to parse the output and determine whether or the computer is bound to a Active Directory domain.

**The problem is the Active Directory domain is returned even the user is logged on as a local user account.**

Note: Ideally I need a solution that works in 10.5 as well.

**Similar Posts that don't answer question:**

[How can I get the domain name for a user logged into a Mac via Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953378/how-can-i-get-the-domain-name-for-a-user-logged-into-a-mac-via-active-directory?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking to how to detect if user has local account or ANY network directory account (ActiveDir or OpenDir). So what I have done using Open Directory framework is like this:

1. get default ODSession session
2. get local node – kODNodeTypeLocalNodes (I don't want to send queries to server all the time)
3. query node for kODAttributeTypeNFSHomeDirectory with querying value set to current user's home directory
4. if found then it means user is local if not (bacause we query local node ony) – user has network account

so something like this:

```
static BOOL  isLocalUser = NO;
static BOOL shouldKeepRunning = YES;        // global

-(BOOL)isLocalUser
{
    isLocalUser = NO;   // set default to NO here
    NSError* err;
    ODSession *mySession = [ODSession defaultSession];
    ODNode *myNode = [ODNode nodeWithSession:mySession type:kODNodeTypeLocalNodes error:&err];
    ODQuery *myQuery = [ODQuery  queryWithNode: myNode
                                forRecordTypes: kODRecordTypeUsers
                                     attribute: kODAttributeTypeNFSHomeDirectory
                                     matchType: kODMatchEqualTo
                                   queryValues: NSHomeDirectory()
                              returnAttributes: kODAttributeTypeStandardOnly
                                maximumResults: 0
                                         error: &err];

    [myQuery retain];
    [myQuery setDelegate: self];
    [myQuery scheduleInRunLoop: [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    NSRunLoop *theRunLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    while (shouldKeepRunning && [theRunLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);

    return isLocalUser;
}

- (void)query:(ODQuery *)inSearch foundResults:(NSArray *)inResults error:(NSError *)inError
{

     if (!inResults && !inError)
     {
        [inSearch removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [inSearch release];
        shouldKeepRunning = NO;  // end of search
     }

     ...
     // check what you found here
     // if found any nodes, user is local so
     isLocalUser = YES;
}
```

Another idea is to use Identity services:

1. get the current user's identity (CSIdentityQueryCreateForCurrentUser)
2. get the authority from that (CSIdentityGetAuthority)
3. see if it's the local authority (CSGetLocalIdentityAuthority)

Hope this helps.