# Check if a user is a local or domain account

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, macos, active-directory

Given the name of a user in OS X, it is possible to query its Active Directory SID using the BSD [membership functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/mbr_sid_to_string.3.html).

However, when a local user name is provided on a machine that is not a member of a directory, an SID is also returned.

A solution for checking if the local logged-in user is a domain account is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904749/mac-osx-determing-whether-user-account-is-an-active-directory-user-vs-local-us/15284509#15284509), but this assumes that the user in question is that of the current session, which may not be the case. In addition, if the user is a mobile account (roaming), then a home directory is found and it returns incorrectly.

So, how would one check if a given username is a local or domain user where the username can be any name, including names used for local processes?

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks for editing the tags, but I'm looking for a solution in any of the languages C, C++ or objective-c, which is the reason for the tags. If you still think these tags are not relevant, please let me know why.

Comment: Tags should represent what your question is about. Your question isn't about any specific language which is why I removed the language tags. You should update your question stating what languages you are willing to work with.

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks for your input. However, after searching Meta, I believe the tags are relevant, as discussed [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281443/how-general-must-a-problem-be-to-warrant-use-of-a-language-library-tag) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281094/tags-is-less-more)

Answer (score 0):

Using *OpenDirectory* API I've managed to achieve a similar task, here is the modified solution that would fit your query:

```
bool isDomainUser(std::string currentUser)
{
    NSString *queryVal = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:currentUser.c_str()];

    ODSession *session = [ODSession defaultSession];

    ODNode *node = [ODNode nodeWithSession:session 
                                type:kODNodeTypeAuthentication error:NULL];

    ODQuery *query = [ODQuery queryWithNode:node forRecordTypes:kODRecordTypeUsers
                                 attribute:kODAttributeTypeRecordName
                                 matchType:kODMatchEqualTo 
                                 queryValues:queryVal
                        returnAttributes:kODAttributeTypeStandardOnly
                        maximumResults:0 error:NULL];

    NSArray *records = [query resultsAllowingPartial:NO error:NULL];

    for (ODRecord *record in records)
    {
        ODAttributeType type = @"dsAttrTypeStandard:OriginalAuthenticationAuthority";
        NSArray *lines = [record valuesForAttribute:type error:nil];

        if (lines)
        {
            for(NSString *line in lines)
            {
                if ([line hasPrefix:@"NetLogon"])
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```